# What's wrong with my NFS setup?

Tags: centos, nfs, autofs

I had previously been able to configure an NFS server on a computer running CentOS 6.6, and to mount the file system in a Virtual Machine with the same OS and using `autofs`.
Last week I did a fresh install of all the OSs I had, and now for some reason I cannot get it to work. The server computer still runs CentOS 6.6, and the Virtual Machine is now running CentOS 7 (I also tried it with another Virtual Machine running Debian Wheezy, but it still didn't work).

The server (`centosserv`) is running on 192.168.1.89, and the client (`centoscli`, the CentOS 7 one) on 192.168.1.100.
The file system I want to share is `/NFSSHARE` and `/NFSSHARE/mydir`, and as such the `/etc/exports` file on the server contains the following:

```
/NFSSHARE       192.168.1.100(fsid=0,rw,sync,no_subtree_check,root_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000)
/NFSSHARE/mydir 192.168.1.100(ro,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

If I run `showmount -e` I get this:

```
[root@centosserv ~]# showmount -e
Export list for centosserv:
/NFSSHARE/mydir 192.168.1.100
/NFSSHARE       192.168.1.100
```

So everything looks good so far.
On the client side, I edited the `/etc/auto.master` to include the following line:

```
/mnt/nfs       /etc/auto.nfs-share       --timeout=90
```

And then created the `/etc/auto.nfs-share` file with the following contents:

```
[root@centoscli ~]# cat /etc/auto.nfs-share
writeable_share        -rw 192.168.1.89:/
non_writeable_share    -ro 192.168.1.89:/mydir
```

This also seems to be working, given the below output:

```
[root@centoscli ~]# mount | grep nfs-share
/etc/auto.nfs-share on /mnt/nfs type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=18,pgrp=2401,timeout=90,minproto=5,maxproto=5,indirect)
```

At this point, `/mnt/nfs/writeable_share` and `/mnt/nfs/non_writeable_share` are not mounted, unless I try to access them directly, as per [this tutorial](http://www.tecmint.com/configure-nfs-server/) (which is the same I had followed the last time I set up the NFS server*). So only after I tried `ls -l /mnt/nfs/writeable_share` should it be mounted. But the output I get is:

```
[root@centoscli ~]# ls -l /mnt/nfs/writeable_share
ls: cannot access /mnt/nfs/writeable_share: No such file or directory
```

I `ping`ed the server from the client and vice versa, just to check that they could both reach each other, and they seem to do.

I did everything exactly the same way I had done the first time round, yet for some reason I cannot get it to work this time. I have tried doing this by editing the `/etc/fstab` file on the client side and manually instead of using `autofs`, but it doesn't seem to work that way either. Disabling `iptables` on the server side makes it work with `fstab` and manually, but not with `autofs` yet.

What else can I check, or where I have gone wrong?

---

*With the exception of the first three steps, since I have neither a service called `nfs-common` neither a `/etc/default/nfs-common` file.

---

**EDIT**

I was checking out [this tutorial on a CentOS group on FB](https://www.facebook.com/notes/centos/mounting-nfs-and-windowscifssamba-filesystem-via-autofs/10150312742892728) that, after the server side is supposedly settled and we're ready to start configuring the client side, says this:

> Test if you can see NFS server:
>   showmount -e

So I'm guessing that using `showmount -e` on the client I should be able to get some info on the server, or it at least some acknowledgement that I can mount file systems from that server on this client. However, I tried using `showmount -e 192.168.1.89` on the client side, and the only message I got was this:

```
 clnt_create: RPC: Port mapper failure - Unable to receive: errno113 (No route to host)
```

I'm guessing this could be the problem, but I'm not sure what it means.

---

**EDIT 2**

After having disabled `iptables` on the server side, I can now see the exported file systems when I use `showmount -e 192.168.1.89` on the client side. Which renders my first edit above moot, I think. However, I am still not able to mount the filesystems using `autofs`.

---

**EDIT 3**

Ok, besides having `iptables` disabled, I have edit both `/etc/exports` on the server and `/etc/auto.nfs-share` on the client to look like this:

```
[root@centosserv ~]# cat /etc/exports
/NFSSHARE          192.168.1.100(fsid=0,rw,sync,no_subtree_check,root_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000)
/NFSSHARE/mydir    192.168.1.100(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,root_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000)
/NFSSHARE/mydir/ro 192.168.1.100(ro,sync,no_subtree_check)

[root@centoscli ~]# cat /etc/auto.nfs-share
writeable_share        -fstype=nfs4,rw 192.168.1.89:/mydir
non_writeable_share    -fstype=nfs4,ro 192.168.1.89:/mydir/ro
```

And with there I seem to be able to *mount* the file systems, but *not to write from the client*:

```
[root@centoscli ~]# touch /mnt/nfs/writeable_share/test_from_client.file
touch: cannot touch ‘/mnt/nfs/writeable_share/test_from_client.file’: Permission denied
```

Comment: I was unsure as to whether the question was a better fit here or on Server Fault. If it is a better fit on the other site, please do migrate it.

Comment: On your client, in `/etc/auto.nfs-share`, aren't you missing the `/NFSSHARE` part of the exported path? What gets written to the syslog by the automounter? IME there should be messages there that point to the error.

Comment: @roaima It is my understanding that I don't need to put `/NFSSHARE` there, since I put `fsid=0` on the exports file on the server. Regarding the syslog, I just checked the client-side, and I found a line containing `automount[1420]: validate_location: invalid character " " found in location rw 192.168.1.89:/`.

Comment: But I think that message above is from before I added a `-` before `rw` on the file, changing `rw 192.168.1.89:/` to `-rw 192.168.1.89:/`, 'cause I was missing that hyphen before.

Comment: Not used nfsv4 (only v3) but it seems from reading around that you're not supposed to try and mount the NFS root. Rather, shares are defined underneath the root point. I'll go have a try unless someone else offers a definitive answer.

Comment: @roaima I've tried it without the `fsid=0` part on the `/etc/exports` file on the server, and by appending the `/NFSSHARE` part on the `/etc/auto.nfs-share` file on the client, but it still didn't work. In any case, I was able to make it work in the first time without these changes, and by mounting the NFS root.

Comment: Can you run `rpcinfo -p 192.168.1.89` on the client, and see if the nfs and mountd handlers are reachable?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick The message I got from that was `rpcinfo: can't contact portmapper: RPC: Remote system error - No route to host`.

Comment: Firewall on both sides? NFS RPC is fickle; it's mostly on ports 111 (portmapper) and 2049 (nfs) but theoretically the nfs port can vary.

Comment: @roaima You mean iptables? If so, how do I check that? I have no idea how to work with iptables yet.

Comment: Sorry, missed that this time. Firewall on client and server - run `iptables -nvL` to get the default filter table, and `iptables -t nat -nvL` for the NAT table that should be irrelevant. Relevant parts are INPUT and OUTPUT. For testing you want to see `policy ACCEPT` and no rules :-)

Comment: @roaima [here](https://gist.github.com/JNat/fd4175e432758eae67fc)'s the output of both the server and the client when running `iptables -nvL`. Can you help me out decoding it, and pointing out to whatever may need to be corrected?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Disabling `iptables` on the server side and then running `rpcinfo -p 192.168.1.89` on the client now gives me [this output](https://gist.github.com/JNat/ccd8944ae136ddae0744).

Comment: That looks much better. Does the `showmount -e 192.168.1.89` command show the exported filesystems now?

Comment: It does. Manually and using `/etc/fstab` I can now mount the file systems. Using `autofs` still gets me nowhere.

Comment: Good. After this gets settled, if you want to re-enable iptables, https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E41138/html/ol_about_nfs.html explains what to do. For NFS v4, you just need to allow access to port 2049. For other versions, you need to hardwire the port numbers used by a few RPC services and then allow access through iptables.

Comment: I've updated the question, since I can now mount the file systems, but still cannot write from the client.

Comment: Not sure if your `touch` is trying to create a new file or touch an existing file. On the server, is `/NFSSHARE/mydir/` (or `/NFSSHARE/mydir/test_from_client.file`) writable by userid or groupid 1000 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It looks like the problem here were the permission settings on the folder being exported on the server side.** So, doing the following on the server allowed me to write from the client:

```
[root@centosserv ~]# chmod 777 /NFSSHARE
```

I did this on fresh installs of both the server and the client. Was experiencing the same problems all over again, and, not even having tried disabling `iptables` on the server and going through the changes I edited into the question this time, decided to make sure that the permissions to `/NFSSHARE` were properly set. Seems to have done the trick.

Comment: And no, it didn't take me a full year to figure it out... I just didn't touch this again for a whole year :P